# How do I prevent access to the system settings for a user or group?

Tags: permissions

I am working to set up Ubuntu 11.10 on our computers at school.

We have a standard account for the students and would like to prevent students from accessing the system settings.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

i think students cant change the system settings if they dont user root user.
if u want to manage groups and user create new account u can get help from the link below.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36845/the-beginners-guide-to-managing-users-and-groups-in-linux/

thanks,

Comment: Not all of the system settings are limited to the root user. Appearance and Keyboard Layout are some of the settings. I need to lock out system settings on the student account so that they can't mess up the computer.